# ASP.Net MVC3 Right click menu (within an Index function of a Controller) does not show "Add View" or "Go To View" options

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

The right click menu when clicked from within the controller area has suddenly stopped showing the "Add View" or "Go To View" options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start as a new MVC project or was it a migration from ASP.NET Web form project to MVC. Did you do anything with the `Project file` ? Try reloading it and see what happens. Check your Project file to see whether you have a `ProjectTypeGuid` for MVC project type. If it is there VS will offer you the context menu for Add View/Controller.

[image]

[Here](http://techiesweb.net/how-to-get-add-view-add-controller-menus-in-solution-explorer-when-converting-existing-asp-net-web-for-project-to-mvc/) is a sample where i have demonstrated how to edit the project file to include the MVC options in an ASP.NET website when you do the conversion.